# SonarQube API result limit

Tags: sonarqube

I have a question about the limit restriction of results in the web api.

There was a restriction to max. 500 results in prior versions. See this
open bug (https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2920) and an old
documentation entry (
http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229743280).

This part is not included in the current documentation (
http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation#api/resources) and my tests
have shown that the api of version 5.1 as well as 4.5.4 is able to deliver
more than 500 results.

So, can the bug be closed and there is no more restriction or do you have a
bug that there is no limitation?

Cheers,

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

There's indeed a bug in this WS, the result should always be limited to 500 : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6584

Regards

Comment: So are you saying there is no way to get more than 500 results from any WS API call?  We have 5.2 and it looks that way to me (or if you can get more I can't figure out how)....

Comment: I said that this WS should be limited to 500, otherwise when there's no limit you have memory issue.

Comment: Other WS should not have this issue, as most of them are paginated and you can navigate through pages.