# How can I pull the right loc information from Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Sonar reports the lines of code iformation for each language on each project's dashboard.

[image]

In order to create a report from 70+ projects, we use THE Sonar's REST API. Currently we iterate over all files of a project to retrieve each file's lines of code. Here we run into the limits issue (the result is cut off at 500 entries, there is no paging on the REST API). See [SonarQube API result limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512888/sonarqube-api-result-limit), and https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2920.

Hence the pulled numbers are wrong, and we need to manually fix the report.

Now my question: Is there a way to pull the numbers shown on the project's dashboard through the REST API? Or going to the database? (Sure, not ideal, but I need to solve my problem ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to go through each file to compute the projects' lines of code ?
Why not use the `api/resources` WS ?

- [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392180)
- [example](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources?metrics=ncloc,coverage&format=json)

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot! Here's the [sample request](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/resources/index?format=json&metrics=ncloc_language_distribution&qualifiers=TRK) for the lines of code per language on a project level. So easy when you know how it works ;-)